# Does wrapping code inside IF FALSE THEN ... END IF have meaning in VBScript?

Tags: c#, vbscript, asp-classic

I working on converting a classic ASP to ASP.NET. And, I keep seeing code wrapped inside the construct.

```
If False Then
 ' code here ...
End If
```

Using a online converter, I get this

```c#
if(false)
{
}
```

Is this code make sense? In visual studio, I'm a getting a warning: `Unreachable code..`

Does wrapping code inside a if statement with false value have meaning in VBScript?

Comment: Looks like it was a way to comment out a block of code they didnt want to delete.

Comment: Which is a pretty stupid way to do it, as it's just more work for the compiler (or interpreter, whatever).  If you want to comment out code, then **comment it out**.

Comment: @LukePark it was useful in VBScript for toggling code blocks, not an issue with the compiler because scripting languages are interpreted and lightweight so any overhead is negligible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a way to comment out code. That and wrapping it in a sub that was never called were the two most used ways to comment blocks of code, and it will never execute, so no, it doesn't make sense in newer languages as we have multi line comments.

The reason this was done was because they only had single apostrophe to do a single line, while you could comment whole blocks by just wrapping it instead of putting an apostrophe in front of every single line.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll even do better by just removing those codes. In fact, the application was developed in late 90's.

Comment: Why the past tense? Are you somehow under the impression that classic asp and vbscript aren't used anymore?

Comment: @Martha Past tense because we have editors for vbscript now, most editors can control comment whole blocks so you don't have to manually insert at the beginning of every line. Modern tools can remove nuisances in old languages